# SQLite não faz insert de dados no banco durante uma AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite, asynctask

Estou tentando adicionar dados no DB dentro de uma AsyncTask.
Nela eu pego a InputStream vindo de um httpURLConnection, interpreto o JSON e salvo no SQLite local. 
Porém eu nem sei se essa é a melhor "pratica" a se fazer...

```
            URL url = new URL(URL);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream())) {
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log(Tags.WSERROR, e.getMessage());
            }

            int status = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inputStream = httpURLConnection.getErrorStream();
                Log(Tags.WSERROR, "Code: " + httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() + "\t\tMsg: " + httpURLConnection.getErrorStream());
            } else {
                inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            }

            mapItens(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }
```

O metodo **MapItens** cuida da interpretação dos dados e de salvar no DB local, esta assim:

```
Map<String, String> mapPedidos(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String linha;

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while ((linha = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer.append(linha + "\n");
    }

    Log(Tags.WSINFO, "Itens - " + buffer.toString());
    if (buffer.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    List<Itens> registers = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject req = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
        Log(Tags.WSINFO, "Itens são: " + req.toString());

        JSONArray locs = req.getJSONArray("DADOS");
        Log(Tags.WSINFO, "locs SIZE: " + locs.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < locs.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject rec = locs.getJSONObject(i);
            Itens it = new Pedido();
            it.nome = rec.getString("IT_NOME");
            it.desc = rec.getString("IT_DESC");
            registers.add(it);
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log(Tags.WSERROR, e.getMessage());
    } finally {


        for (Itens i : registers) {
            Log(Tags.WSINFO, "Item : " + i.nome + " sendo criado!");
            boolean r = i.create();

            if (r)
                Log(Tags.WSINFO, i.nome + " created!");
            else
                Log(Tags.WSINFO, i.nome + " error");
        }

        Log(Tags.WSINFO, "Count in DB: " + getInstance().getCount());
        getInstance().CloseDB();
    }

    ArrayList<Itens> p = Itens.getAll();
    Log(Tags.WSINFO, "Select nos itens iniciando");
    if (p != null)
        for (Itens pe : p) {
            Log(Tags.WSINFO, "Itens " + pe.nome);
        }
    Log(Tags.WSINFO, "Select nos itens finalizando");

    if (httpURLConnection != null) {
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }

    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }

    return getData;

}
```

Eu fiz essa mesma lógica em outra classe para obter outras informações de outro webservice. Ela funciona perfeitamente.

Outro ponto é que não há exception na inserção dos dodos no DB, o resultado sai como true, o getCount() da tabela me retorna numero de resgistros positivos.
Em todos os logs, as informações são mostradas corretamente.
Quando eu faço o select, **o ArrayList de itens vem nulo**, aparentemente.
O maior problema é que no restante de todo aplicativo, esses metodos de select do SQLite funcionam normalmente.